How does APIGW -> VPC Link -> Internet Facing ALB work?
We have an architecture where the APIGW has a private integration to a Internet-facing ALB using VPC Link. I want to understand what is the need for VPC Link here and is it even useful? If yes, does the traffic reach to the private IP of the ALB or does it pass through public internet?
My ALB Security group has a rule allowing all traffic from the internet, which is what I want to avoid.
APIGW:

Integration type in APIGW: Private Resource
Target Service: Application, Internet-facing Load balancer
Listener: HTTPS 443

VPC Link:

Subnet CIDRs: 10.131.104.0/24, 10.131.102.0/24, 10.131.103.0/24

VPC Link Subnets' Route Table (Relevant rules):

10.131.96.0/20: Local
0.0.0.0/0: Transit Gateway

ALB:

Subnet CIDRs: 10.131.105.0/25, 10.131.105.128/25, 10.131.106.0/25

Note: VPC Flow Logs are not enabled and I couldn't find relevant documentation to clear my queries.

What is the flow of the traffic here? Any documentation/way to verify it without access logs and VPC Flow Logs
Is the VPC Link useful here? If not, how can I route the traffic from APIGW to ALB?
How to avoid using 0.0.0.0 rule in ALB Security Group?
I read that fronting the ALB with a private NLB will solve the issue, what will be the security group rule in that case be? Will it result in additional costs?

Edit:
The ALB HAS to be public because Cloudfront also sends requests to it. Cloudfront only works with internet-facing ALB.

Why did you create a public load balancer if you don't want the load balancer to be public? No, a private load balancer will not cost more. Network load balancers have a specific setting you can enable, that lets all VPC Link traffic bypass security group rules, so you won't need security group rules at all. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-nlb-for-vpclink-using-console.html

Public loadbalancer is required for cloudfront to work with ALB

You make no mention of CloudFront in your question at all.

It sounds like you have a public website served by the ALB. Are you trying to only make certain paths (/api/* or something) go through the API Gateway?

Yes, certain paths go through Cloudfront -> APIGW -> ALB, rest of them go through Cloudfront -> ALB

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
